# How to use s/ for the keys in a hash?

Tags: perl

I have a hash %defines_3 which looks like this

```
      'PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD' => 'CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR',
      'PIOMUX_UART_1_TXD' => 'CONFIG_PIO22_7_SELECTOR',
      'PIOMUX_UART_11_TXD' => 'CONFIG_PIO0_4_SELECTOR',
      'PIOMUX_UART_10_TXD' => 'CONFIG_PIO0_1_SELECTOR',
      'PIOMUX2_UART_1_TXD' => 'CONFIG_PIO25_2_SELECTOR',
      'PIOMUX_UART_3_TXD' => 'CONFIG_PIO32_6_SELECTOR',
```

To change some parts from all keys and values I did like this :

```
  for (values %defines_3)    
{ 
 s/CONFIG_/PIO_M_U_/g; 
 s/_SELECTOR//g;
 }

 for (keys %defines_3)  
{
s/_TXD//g;
}

 print Dumper \%defines_3;
```

after which I am getting this :

```
      'PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO31_6',
      'PIOMUX_UART_1_TXD' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO22_7',
      'PIOMUX_UART_11_TXD' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO0_4',
      'PIOMUX_UART_10_TXD' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO0_1',
      'PIOMUX2_UART_1_TXD' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO25_2',
      'PIOMUX_UART_3_TXD' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO32_6',
```

So basically I am not able to substitute the keys but the values are being substituted the way i want by using s/ . How to change keys?

Comment: You've been asked before to indent your Perl code properly so that it's readable. It's only polite when you are asking for help for free, and it will help you to read your own code and solve your own problems.

Comment: @Borodin  Sorry I will take care of that in future .

Comment: Asking how to use s/// on the indexes of a hash like asking how to use s/// on the index of an array. Makes no sense. Delete the old element and recreate it with the new key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`values()` are producing [`lvalues`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#L) which are due `foreach` aliased to `$_` and thus can be directly changed. `keys()` must be deleted from hash in order to be changed,

```
for (keys %defines_3)   {
  my $v = delete $defines_3{$_};
  s/_TXD//g;
  $defines_3{$_} = $v;
}
```

or for newer perl which has support for `/r` switch,

```
for (keys %defines_3)   {
  $defines_3{ s/_TXD//gr } = delete $defines_3{$_};
}
```

Comment: TMTOWTDI, `my @v = values %h; s/_TXD//g for my @k = keys %h; %h =(); @h{@k} = @v;`

Comment: thanks a lot :) So basically we had to store the values for corresponding keys somewhere else , then change the keys and put the values back ..am i right ?? and what did you do by doing  %h =() ?

Comment: @Grace90 yes, you have to delete them first. `%h =();` empties the hash (assigning empty list).

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename hash keys, as they are stored as simple C strings and not Perl scalar variables. To achieve the same effect you can delete the hash element and reinsert it using a new key.

Usefully, the `delete` operator returns the hash element's value, so you could write it like this.

Note that it is normally unwise to modify a hash or an array while you are iterating over it, but it is safe in this instance because the `keys %data` expression returns a fixed list of all of the hash keys that is separate from the hash itself.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = (
  PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD => 'CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR',
  PIOMUX_UART_1_TXD  => 'CONFIG_PIO22_7_SELECTOR',
  PIOMUX_UART_11_TXD => 'CONFIG_PIO0_4_SELECTOR',
  PIOMUX_UART_10_TXD => 'CONFIG_PIO0_1_SELECTOR',
  PIOMUX2_UART_1_TXD => 'CONFIG_PIO25_2_SELECTOR',
  PIOMUX_UART_3_TXD  => 'CONFIG_PIO32_6_SELECTOR',
);

for my $key ( keys %data) {
  (my $new_key = $key)               =~ s/_TXD$//;
  (my $new_val = delete $data{$key}) =~ s/^CONFIG_(.+)_SELECTOR$/PIO_M_U_$1/;
  $data{$new_key} = $new_val;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{
  PIOMUX2_UART_1 => "PIO_M_U_PIO25_2",
  PIOMUX2_UART_3 => "PIO_M_U_PIO31_6",
  PIOMUX_UART_1  => "PIO_M_U_PIO22_7",
  PIOMUX_UART_10 => "PIO_M_U_PIO0_1",
  PIOMUX_UART_11 => "PIO_M_U_PIO0_4",
  PIOMUX_UART_3  => "PIO_M_U_PIO32_6",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easiest by using the `pairmap` function from `List::Util`. Its block is executed once for each key/value pair in the input list, and whatever list of values it returns is collected, like a regular `map`. This makes it easy to build a new hash out of an old one:

```
use 5.014;  # for the s///r syntax
use List::Util qw( pairmap );

my %new_hash = pairmap {
   ( $a =~ s/_TXD$//r, $b =~ s/^CONFIG_(.+)_SELECTOR$/PIO_M_U_$1/r )
} %old_hash;
```

If you're stuck before 5.14 without the `s///r` syntax, you can do it with

```
use List::Util qw( pairmap );

my %new_hash = pairmap {
   my ( $key, $val ) = ( $a, $b );
   $key =~ s/_TXD$//;
   $val =~ s/^CONFIG_(.+)_SELECTOR$/PIO_M_U_$1/;
   ( $key, $val )
} %old_hash;
```